# Rightarrow with a Delta on it (for use with the mhchem package)

Tags: arrows, mhchem, chemistry

I have a small problem with arrows. I need a `\rightarrow` with a `\Delta` on it. Can you help me, please? I use the chemistry package `\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}`.

Comment: The `stackengine` package can do these things.   For example, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\( A \stackon[2pt]{\rightarrow}{\scriptstyle\Delta} B \)
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mhchem`'s formulas implicitly use math mode so you can use `\Delta` directly. The syntax inside `mhchem`'s `\ce{}` macro for a right arrow is:

```
->[above][below]
```

where both arguments are optional and `above` and `below` are placed in math mode. (`mhchem` also loads `amsmath` by the way.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{ A + B ->[\Delta] C }
\end{document}
```

[image]

The [`mhchem` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mhchem) actually has an example for this :)

[image]